# session timeout never happens if I use -1 inside web.xml/session-config

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, server

What happens when I use -1 inside web.xml's session-config attribute. I can disable session-timeout by doing that ?

Such Like :

```
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>-1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

Regards

Comment: that is exactly what -1 means never time out.

Comment: See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval-int-) of the `HttpSession`.

Answer (score 2):

What server are you using? But normally, yes! Doing so, sessions never expire.

EDIT: The [JEE Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm#WBAPP531) says that but it depends on the application server implementation